# Trying to recognise a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and $X=B(H,K)$ denotes the spaces of bounded linear operators. For $T_1, T_2$ in $X$, we define $D_{T_1,T_2}:X \to X$ as $D_{T_1,T_2}(T)=TT_1^*T_2$. Finally define $V^0=$span$\{D_{T_1,T_2}, T_1, T_2 \in X\}$. One can check that $V^0$ is pre $C^*$-algebra with involution $D_{T_1,T_2}^*=D_{T_2,T_1}$. Let $V$ denotes the closure of $V^0$ inside $B(X)$.

> Is $V$ isomorphic to some well known $C^*$-algebra?

I was trying to classify it with $B(H)$ but was unable to do it. Any hints?

Comment: I can't even see why $V^0$ is a $*$-algebra in general

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: $D_{T_1,T_2}^*=D_{T_2,T_1}$

Comment: do you define this to be this way?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: Yes, with this involution $V^0$ becomes pre $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: Can you add some context, why are you studying this thing, what is the multiplication and what norm are you considering here?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: Please see $3.2$ Proposition of [this](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/000187088390083X?token=01B8E5AC9D0B68D9B1C3816A5724216F3593567C5DB7B706F1E7859093E031641858701A9AA2ECD58D273F5FFED0E1D4&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210901064606)